# How to send output result into ZMQ pub sink and read from sub source

Tags: python, zeromq, gnuradio, pyzmq

Hi I am trying to send the printed output result from main_block.reader.print_results() over to the GNURadio ZMQ Pub sink to my database using ZMQ sub source. How do I do it?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  main_block = reader_top_block()
  main_block.start()

  while(1):
    inp = input("'Q' to quit \n")
    if (inp == "q" or inp == "Q"):
      break

  main_block.reader.print_results()
  main_block.stop()
```

P.S. I am new to ZMQ and trying it for the first time.

Comment: Please make sure to have MCVE question (reproducible results) to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your  `main_block.reader` is. Anyway, it sounds as if it prints stuff. So parallel that, simply connect a ZMQ Pub sink. That's all.

Comment: Hi Marcus, how do I store the printed message into a python variable?

Comment: you don't. It doesn't solve your problem here!